# Symfony2 redirect to an externel url in new tab

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a function that redirect to an external URL with parametre, but I want to redirect it to a new tab , 
This my code

```
 public function urlAction(){

    $directory= $user->getDirectory();
           return $this->redirect('http://localhost/sound/index.html?directory='.$directory );

}
```

I want to open the link in new tab. any suggestion please?

Comment: AFAIK, the user decides whether he wants to open a link in a tab. Just like I CTRL+clicked this question to open it in a separate tab.

Comment: `<a href="link" target="_blank">target site</a>`

Comment: Use `target="blank"` on a link. There is no such thing as "redirecting into a new tab/window".

Comment: @PietervandenHam I'm not sure how many common users even know that key combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer possible here is that **you can't redirect in a new tab**.

You can provide links that open in a new tab or window using the target in html or a function in php, but you can't have a redirect.